# Porting a silverlight application to iPad

Tags: silverlight, ipad

Does silverlight applications run on iPad. If not, what is the nearest equivalent that can be used with iPad to which porting of an existing silverlight application can be done.

Comment: Is there a iPad applciation that allows remote desktop connections? If yes, you can connect to other computer and display the screen with the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can't port your silverlight views to the ipad or iphone, but you may be able to port your c# view models and backend code to run on monotouch (the .Net runtime for iPhoneOS).

That said, I'd wait for [Xamarin](http://www.xamarin.com/) to release thier replacement to Monotouch first.

There is a small/medium chance that Xamarin will support xaml views (silverlight 4.0) on iphoneOS at some point in the future.